# QML StackView получить объект

Tags: qt5, qml

Не могу понять что я делаю не так. 
StackView в нем пять элементов Page. 
Мне нужно перейти из пятого в третий
В пятом Page пример кода:

```
stackView.pop({item:"qrc:/views/TestThree.qml", immediate: true})
```

Получаю пустое окно без элементов управления. Если нажимаю крестик на приложении, то происходит ещё раз pop() судя по анимации перехода, и оказываюсь на третьем элементе.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Нужно больше кода, но подозреваю, что вы не совсем правильно используете `stackView.pop` - не думаю, что он принимает url файла qml

Comment: Он действительно принимает url. Проблему решил костылем, просто добавил дополнительный сигнал pop(), но нормальный вариант так и не заработал